# VB.net Casting 2D objects to 1 Array

Tags: vb.net, string, casting

I am running into a simple issue for which I cannot find an effective solution.

I need to convert 2 D array of objects to 1D String.

```
Dim saRet(,) As Object = Nothing
Dim fileLineArray() As String = Nothing

.
.
SaRet = xlrange.Value //it gets values assigned as objects
In a loop....
fileLineArray(i) = Cstr(SaRet(i,0))
```

I get the error, index was out of bound.

.ToString isnt able to convert 2d array of objects to 1 D.

Comment: Did you dimension fileLineArray before trying to assign a value to it?

Comment: I intend to declare an array without bounds. Therefore I initialized it during the declaration as nothing.

Comment: You can't just assign an element of an array a value without first dimensioning it. If you don't know the number of dimensions at the time you could use a generics instead: Dim fileLineArray As New List(Of String)

Answer (score 0):

Perhapes a `ReDim Preserve` is in order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only `ReDim Preserve` the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array (meaning you can't change the number of dimensions). Also, `ReDim Preserve` is super-duper-bad in general.